# JUnit Tests Scanner error: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, junit, java.util.scanner

Currently running `JUnit` tests and I keep getting the above error. I've declared a public, static Scanner in my class and then access it from a different package which contains the test classes:

The following code (in ClassA) will keep on looping until user enters correct input.

```
public static Scanner sc;

public boolean methodInClass() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (; ; ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            System.out.println("Please enter character. Enter A/B/C/D");
            char guess = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (!correct) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a new guess");

                guess = sc.next().charAt(0);

            } 

///rest of code
```

In the test class:

This is an @Test method, and uses the following lines to simulate the Scanner:

```
String input = "L\nL\nD\nU\nA\n";
System.setIn(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));
ClassA.sc = new Scanner(System.in); //should stop at A which is correct input
```

Comment: If you're testing input from the command line, you may have a look at the System Rules library: http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change correct value to TRUE, so it checks all 5 leters, trys to take 6th, and crashes. 
After

```
char guess = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

add

```
correct = guess=='A';
```

also, your top for cycle never ends. So you probably want add break somewhere.

Edit: and while correct == false you are reading 1st, 3rd, 5th symbol. Probably you didn't intended to do that.